# Linux user interface programming? (esp. for Python and Fortran)

Tags: gui, programming

What are my options for programming a GUI in Linux? I have several programs in Fortran and Python that I would like to create simple UI's for. I also plan on incorporating graphics in the form of plots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're going to need a GUI toolkit. There are more available than I can list here. Python has bindings for more toolkits than you can shake a stick at. See their [GUI Programming](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) wiki page for more info. I don't know much about Fortran, but the same logic is going to apply.

The most common toolkits on Linux are [GTK](http://www.gtk.org/) (originally developed for The GIMP and now used in most Gnome stuff), the [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) tookit (most famous for being used in KDE) and [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). [Tk](http://tcl.sourceforge.net/) is an oldy but a goody that seems to have bindings almost everywhere.

I would recommend researching which one you want to work with based on your target platform, what has the widgets most similar to what you want, and then using the same toolkit for all your work across both Python and Fortran since using the toolkit will almost be a language of it's own.

Answer (score 2):

There are so many options, the variety is mind boggling.  Some of the more popular GUI frameworks include.

- [GTK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GTK+)
- [WX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WxWidgets)
- [QT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_%28framework%29)
- [TK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_%28framework%29)